# How to set a binding to an element that was not instantiated in XAML code

Tags: binding

I´m relative new to coding and I´m working on a little project. This is what I´m trying to do:

I defined a class "MyObject" with two properties:

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
  public class MyObject
  {
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }

    public MyObject() : this("", 0)
    {
    }

    public MyObject(string p1, int p2)
    {
        Property1 = p1;
        Property2 = p2;
    }
  }
}
```

...then instantiated two objects of this class in code:

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{

  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public List<MyObject> listOfMyObject { get; set; }
    public MyObject myObj1 { get; set; }
    public MyObject myObj2 { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listOfMyObject = new List<MyObject>();
        myObj1 = new MyObject("Hello", 1);
        myObj2 = new MyObject("Bye", 2);
        listOfMyObject.Add(myObj1);
        listOfMyObject.Add(myObj2);
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to bind each property of the two MyObject objects to the Content Property of a Label object. So there should be four Label objects:
- Label1 should display the value of Property1 of myObj1
- Label2 should display the value of Property2 of myObj1
- Label3 should display the value of Property1 of myObj2
- Label4 should display the value of Property2 of myObj2

I tried it this way:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="mywin">
  <Grid>
      <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"  Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Name="Label1" Content="{Binding ElementName=myObj1, Path=Property1}"/>
            <Label Name="Label2" Content="{Binding ElementName=myObj1, Path=Property2}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Name="Label3" Content="{Binding ElementName=myObj2, Path=Property1}"/>
            <Label Name="Label4" Content="{Binding ElementName=myObj2, Path=Property2}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

... but it doesn´t work. Please help me to understand how to use the Binding correctly!

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

// Even if I already figured out how to solve my problem, I would be pleased, // if someone could answer to the question at the end of this post!

Okay, now I figured out (with a little help from a friend), how to fix my problem:

I set the DataContext property of the MainWindow object, that contained the Label objects to itself by doing this:

```
mywin.DataContext = this;
```

So the code looks like this now:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<MyObject> listOfMyObject { get; set; }

    public MyObject myObj1 { get; set; }

    public MyObject myObj2 { get; set; }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listOfMyObject = new List<MyObject>();
        myObj1 = new MyObject("Hello", 1);
        myObj2 = new MyObject("Bye", 2);
        listOfMyObject.Add(myObj1);
        listOfMyObject.Add(myObj2);

        // I added this code
        mywin.DataContext = this;
    }

}
```

And then I set the binding to the Content property of the four Label objects by doing this:

```
<Label Name="Label1" Content="{Binding Path=myObj1.Property1}" />
```

So my whole XAML code looks like this now:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="mywin">
  <Grid>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"  Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Name="Label1" Content="{Binding Path=myObj1.Property1}" />
            <Label Name="Label2" Content="{Binding Path=myObj1.Property2}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Name="Label3" Content="{Binding Path=myObj2.Property1}" />
            <Label Name="Label4" Content="{Binding Path=myObj2.Property2}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

NEW Question:
Now I would like to understand, why it doesn´t work the way I tried in the first way...

```
<Label Name="Label1" Content="{Binding ElementName=myObj1, Path=Property1}"/>
```

... when this would work:

```
<Label Name="Label1" Content="{Binding ElementName=Label2, Path=Content}"/>
<Label Name="Label2" Content="Hello">
```

The XAML code, in which the Label objects are instantiated and the C# code, in which the MyObject objects are instantiated, are both partial classes that belong together. In addition to that the MyObject objects myObj1 and myObj2 are properties of this class. So I thought that the Label-Elements in the XAML code should "know" about the MyObject objects myObj1 and myObj2 and therefore be able to reference them as source elements in the ElementName property of the Binding object. Thinking this way, I thought I must only set the Path property of the Binding object to the Property which value the Label object should display.
Can you help me to understand, where my idea of Binding is wrong? Thank you!